# Number of features in MLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

How do I change the number of features in MLP, in python code? For example I got 300 data samples into an `numpy` array as input and I want to have each time 3 features or 4 or whatever. How I can do that? Thanks!
To make in clear I have this

```
[84.95999819 79.83999899 88.27999839 83.74999791 80.00999899 84.9999982
 84.33999793 82.05999835 83.37999795 80.34999898 78.53999869 79.55999899
 86.85999873 87.52999832 79.51999899 84.72999809 82.919998   79.81999899
 80.85999891 87.02999861]
```

And I want it to use it as input with 3 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're likely asking how to make a two dimensional numpy array so you want something like:

```
a = np.empty((number_of_examples, number_of_features))
```

Then you can assign into that array as necessary.

Comment: Can you be more specific how i put my data in the array a and select for example 4 features?